# Euclidean distance from a point (x,y) to the diagonal line not make sense when plotting the dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame:

```
data_new
           X         Y dis
1  123.99561  51.91563  51
2   37.88886  58.53972  15
3  141.40895  63.65503  55
4  119.14452  30.76315  62
5  274.76553  86.58737 133
6   47.52072  45.31681   2
7   95.85810  50.61795  32
8   67.15455  32.80465  24
9  154.51721  47.30627  76
10  48.44236  28.53955  14
11  31.81736  37.71708   4
12  25.88461  30.42648   3
13 236.74989  67.73648 120
14  99.48136  24.94934  53
15  23.36206  39.49535  11
16  24.44889  37.43396   9
17 113.75209  80.35577  24
18  95.45518  29.98268  46
19  28.81779  43.61353  10
20 199.56171  26.04967 123
21 111.38701  40.14422  50
22 284.14249  59.72049 159
23  63.29509  25.16359  27
24 227.48874  41.13283 132
25 125.92173  84.18931  30
26  51.42495  46.09882   4
27 215.53986  54.20816 114
28  81.68309  48.08828  24
29 144.99979  79.08405  47
30 125.25327  33.18417  65
31 107.41949  27.30456  57
32  68.18888  34.59822  24
33  24.66347  53.77048  21
34 142.25804  39.52901  73
35  45.39493  21.50758  17
36 410.58755 168.68774 171
37  37.72387  20.73628  12
38  88.80147  24.92792  45
39 104.97260  20.85106  59
40 180.27368  72.85551  76
41 181.45314  45.02298  96
42 191.04002  41.63631 106
43  39.53319  26.83474   9
44 102.12894  42.60350  42
45 215.98138  74.87252 100
46 110.32643  32.65773  55
47 111.40245 106.77119   3
48 444.09225 150.84842 207
49 104.60363  47.16242  41
50 207.58011  35.09406 122
```

The col "dis" is the calculation of each dot's distance to the diagonal line.
Calculated as abs(Y - X) / sqrt(2).

Then, I plot out:

```
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y), alpha = 1, size = 2, colour = "red") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = X, y = Y, label = dis), max.overlaps = 20) +
  geom_abline(intercept = c(0, 1, -1), slope = 1, linetype = c("solid","dashed", "dashed"), color = c("blue", "orange", "orange")) +
  scale_x_continuous("X",
                     trans = "asinh",
                     limits = c(1, 10^5, 10),
                     breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  scale_y_continuous("Y",
                     trans = "asinh", 
                     limits = c(1, 10^5, 10),
                     breaks = c(1,10,100,1000,10000,100000),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  annotation_logticks(sides = "bl", outside = TRUE) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "bl", outside = TRUE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 10),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -1, size = 15, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = -1, size = 15, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 3, size = 18))
```

The plot looks so different from my expectation.

[image]

first, I lay down two parallel lines along the diagonal line, intercept = 1/-1, theoretically, the dots on the y = x+1 line should have abs(1)/sqrt(2) distance from y=x line. But based on those calculated dots, all of them have "dis" value of more than 1. Did I run the wrong calculation?
Second, the dot has a value 207 is even closed to the diagonal line than the dot has a value 159. I'm so confused.
I asinh transferred the x and y-axis, is that the reason that may impact the plotting?

Thanks.

Comment: What probably is happening is that you're transforming both axes and the intercepts aren't transformed accordingly. Possibly relevant discussion: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3741

Comment: But it's still not an answer about dot207 is even close to diagonal than dot159. The distance calculation should not be impacted by the x/y transformation.